# How to evaluate multiple arguments and get multiple outputs with cellfun in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Suposse the next two variables:

```
A={[];[1 2];[3]};
B={[10 20 30];[40 50 60];[70 80 90]};
```

I need to get C1 and C2, who are:

```
C1={[];[40 50];[90]}; % Corresponding value B(A), like B{2,1}([1 2])=[40 50];
C2={[];[45];[90]}; % Mean, like for ex: mean(B{2,1}([1 2]))=mean([40 50])=45;
```

As you can see, I need to make something with a **cellfun**, but I don't know how to evaluate two or more input arguments, and have two or more outputs.

like:

```
[C1,C2]=cellfun(@function,A,B)
```

I'll really appreciate any information, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with `arrayfun` and `cellfun`. First compute `C1`,  and from that compute `C2`:

```
C1 = arrayfun(@(k) B{k}(A{k}), 1:size(A,1), 'UniformOutput', false);
C2 = cellfun(@mean, C1);
```